# Galing- does not display session variable

Tags: session-variables, gatling

I try to substitute session variable in the request payload, and it doesn't work,

I am reading from csv file

```
empNo, orderNo
74726,[49 50]
71696,[52 51 53 50 37 36 38]
```

```
object BidSubmission extends HttpUtil {

  val orders_feeder = csv("data/Round-1.csv").circular

  def orderSubmission: ChainBuilder =
    pause(pauseBy(5) seconds)
      .repeat(1) {
        feed(orders_feeder)
          .exec(postToUri(s"${Constants.orderSubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/proxy-bid", "")
            .queryParam("employeeId", "#{empNo}")
            .body(StringBody(session => {
              println(session)
              println(session.attributes("empNo"))
              val empNo = session.attributes("empNo").asInstanceOf[String]
              val orderNo = session.attributes("orderNo").asInstanceOf[String]
              println(s"\n\n\n $orderNo \n\n\n")
              var slotNos = orderNo.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(" +")
              println(s"\n\n\n ${generatePayload(empNo, slotNos)} \n\n\n")
              generatePayload(empNo, slotNos)
              " "
            }))
          )
      }

  private def generatePayload(empNo: String, orderNo: Array[String]) = {
    s"""
       | {
       |    "submittedAt": ${DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(OffsetDateTime.now)}
       |    "allowSameMonth": false,
       |    "allowConsecutiveMonths": true,
       |    "selections": [
                 ${generateSlotNo(orderNo)}
       |    ]
       |}
       |""".stripMargin
  }


  private def generateSlotNo(orderNo: Array[String]) = {
    orderNo.map(slotNo => s"\"${Constants.proxySubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/00000-00000-00000/order-slots/${slotNo}\"").mkString(",")
  }
}
```

1. AuctionId session variable is printed in the log, however it is not assigned inside the generateSlotNo method.
   in generateSlotNo, AuctionId value is not substituted. It actually prints #{AuctionId} as it is, Can you please help me what i am missing here?

{
"submittedAt": 2023-02-12T22:51:47.860567-06:00
"allowSameMonth": false,
"allowConsecutiveMonths": true,
"selections": [
"https://service.east.cbna.dev1.dev.aws.swacorp.com/golden/base-auction/crew/auctions/#{AuctionId}/base-auctions/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/bid-slots/49","https://service.east.cbna.dev1.dev.aws.swacorp.com/golden/base-auction/crew/auctions/#{AuctionId}/base-auctions/0da65bd8-a25f-4b2c-b2f6-2a7f5b0f6432/bid-slots/50"
]
}

2. Can you please tell me how i can capture the post request - URI in the test? ie the URI that we are sending the post request to.

Answer (score 0):

As [explained in the documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/), Gatling Expression Language only works in Strings passed to Gatling DSL methods.

You can't use it in your own custom code, so you have to explicitly pass the value you want for `AuctionId` in `generateSlotNo`.

Comment: Do i have to capture AuctionId session variable like this?
 val auctionId = session.attributes("AcutionId").asInstanceOf[String] and pass to generateSlotNo(orderNo, auctionId) ---> Can you please advise?

Comment: Yes, that's what you have to do.

Comment: ok, thank you, I was able to substitute actionId this time, and To form the POST Uri request, I use {$AuctionId} in the code i posted in the question, Can I use session variable #{$AuctionId} directly in the URI like this unlike generateSlotNo method >.exec(postToUri(s"${Constants.orderSubmission_URL}/#{$AuctionId}/base-orders/proxy-bid", "").              ,Secondly, I am not sure how to print the POST request URI to make sure if the URI is formed correctly, Question 2 - that i posted in the question above, Can you please advise?